# How should I sink Apache-flink stream data into Druid?

Tags: apache-flink, druid

I am wondering what is the best way to directly sink Apache-Flink stream data into Druid.

I know Tranquility, but it does not support the latest Flink and Druid. Does anyone know a better solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [latest docs](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/tranquility.html), the recommended architecture would appear to be Flink -> Kafka -> Druid.